# Writing to extConf in extbase controller

Tags: typo3, backend, global

I have a litte extbase extension that changes my color settings (e.g. css, cookiebar, etc.), and I also want to change the color of the backend plugin button, in the `backend` sysext in my controller.

Getting the value:

```
$var = unserialize($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['extConf']['backend']);
$var["loginHighlightColor"]="#444444";
```

But now, how do I save the value?
When trying the following statement, it sets the value correctly but it doesn't get persisted:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['extConf']['backend'] = serialize($var);
```

Even trying to persist manually with the PersistentManager doesn't work.

Comment: Do not use the extension configuration to safe configuration values on the fly. Store them somewhere else, e.g. the TYPO3 registry or in configuration record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Bernd Wilke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6796354/bernd-wilke-%cf%80%cf%86) I got it:

```
$var = unserialize($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['extConf']['backend']);
$var["loginHighlightColor"]="#444444";

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['extConf']['backend'] = serialize($var);

$configurationUtility = $this->objectManager->get(\TYPO3\CMS\Extensionmanager\Utility\ConfigurationUtility::class);
$newConfiguration = $configurationUtility->getCurrentConfiguration("backend");
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ArrayUtility::mergeRecursiveWithOverrule($newConfiguration, $var);
$configurationUtility->writeConfiguration(
    $configurationUtility->convertValuedToNestedConfiguration($newConfiguration),
    "backend"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how it works inside my AdditionalConfiguration.php. Maybe you can adapt it:

```
$resourcePath = 'EXT:' . $extKey . '/Resources/Public/Images/';
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['extConf']['backend'] = serialize(
    [
        'loginLogo'            => $resourcePath . 'logo.svg',
        'loginHighlightColor'  => '#c0c0c0',
        'loginBackgroundImage' => $resourcePath . 'login-bg.svg',
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you propably need to do the same than found here:

http://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/current/html/_configuration_controller_8php_source.html#l00156

as that function is protected you can't call it from your code. 
there are two public functions you possibly can use:

public function saveAction(array $config, $extensionKey) (line 109)

public function saveAndCloseAction(array $config, $extensionKey) (line 131)